# How to remove ghost lines around polygons in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm trying to remove the very thin, yet visible white "ghost" lines in between polygons. You can see This in the image below.

[image]

Hopefully you don't have to strain your eyes to see that there are very thin white lines in between each of the polygons. I've made the lines transparent and given them a thickness of 0, but they're still there. Here are my settings:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to solve the problem or workaround solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your border color to the same color as your fill.

With QGIS 2.14 if you are creating a categorized/graduated symbology you can even set up a data defined override of:  @symbol_color

Which will automatically assign the same color to the border as the fill.

You can set this up as a data defined override:

[image]

Comment: How would you set that override up?

Comment: Added image with override location.