# Apply color ramp to marker outline

Tags: qgis, color-ramp, data-defined-override

I have a point layer in QGIS 2.18.14. I have colored the points based on a category, using the YlOrRd color ramp. Now I am trying to change the outline of each point marker to be slightly darker than the fill color. I would do it by hand, but there are dozens of them. Is there a way to do this automatically?

I have tried applying a data-defined override to the outline of the simple marker using the expression "darker(@symbol_color, 200)" as presented in solutions to these questions:

[Styling border to match fill in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191022/styling-border-to-match-fill-in-qgis)

[How to remove ghost lines around polygons in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198288/how-to-remove-ghost-lines-around-polygons-in-qgis-2-12/198291#198291)

but it does not result in any change. In the expression window, the output preview shows that it's working, but the actual color of the outline just never changes. I tested the same method on a polygon layer (because both previous questions were talking about polygons, not points), and still got nothing. Any idea how I might do this better, or why the data defined override isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

It's working for me - maybe try setting the size and outline values to MAP UNITS to get something more dramatic:

[image]