# Change all stroke style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to remove all strokes of boundary of categories by selecting
"Symobol selector"->"Stroke style"->"No pen"

However, if there are a large amount of symbols, it is impossible to change all.
Are there any measures to change all symbols at one time?

[image]

Comment: using no stroke will leave a tiny white space around each polygon. You may want to keep a solid line but to color it using the same color as the fill color [like here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198288/how-to-remove-ghost-lines-around-polygons-in-qgis-2-12/198291#198291)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Symbology", if you select all symbols, then click in the "Symbol" area (in your screenshot it was in green), then `Simple Fill`, and select a `Stroke Width` (or any other style), it will be applied to all symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Click below all your classes so none is selected.

Then click on the master symbol at the very top and adjust the outline, it will be automatically applied to all classes

[image]